# Scrapy ignores deny rule

Tags: python, scrapy

As a newbie in scrapy and python, I'm struggling with the deny rules of my Crawl Spider. I want to filter all URLs on my target page, which contain the word "versicherung" and the double ? structure in any part of the URL. However, scrapy ignores my rule. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the syntax (I've already tried without the "" before the *, but that doesn't work either)?

Rule:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=r'\*versicher\*', r\'*\?*\?\*',),
            callback='parse_norisbank', follow=True)]
```

Log:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.norisbank.de/produkte/versicherungen/rechtsschutzversicherung.html> (referer: https://www.norisbank.de)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.norisbank.de/produkte/versicherungen/haftpflichtversicherung.html> (referer: https://www.norisbank.de)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.norisbank.de/produkte/versicherungen/hausratversicherung.html> (referer: https://www.norisbank.de)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.norisbank.de/produkte/versicherungen/versicherungsmanager.html> (referer: https://www.norisbank.de)
DEBUG: Saved file nbtest-versicherungen.html
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied your code in correctly.  The `r\'*` is not a regular expression

Comment: This was an act of desperation... without the regex "r" it isn't working, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules must be regular expressions and (even if I correct your syntax) you are not using `*` correctly.

`r'\*versicher\*'` should be `r'.*versicher.*'` EDIT: looking at scrapy docs, it looks like `r'versicher'` is sufficient.

I don't understand what you mean by "double ? structure", but your URLs don't seem to have it.

I expect `r'.*\?\?.*'` is what you want (or `r'\?\?'`)

In regular expressions

- `.` means any character
- `*` means 0 or more of the preceding (so `.*` matches anything)
- `\\` is how you escape a special character.  You don't want to escape the `*` since you want it to act in its special way.

Comment: Thank you, Lou! This works, and even more makes me finally understand the use of the regular expresions. I have tried with 'versicher' before, but that hasn't worked, either. Regarding the double-? thing, I want to filter all URLS which contain two question marks. So r'.*\\?.*\\?.*' should do the trick.